# Shape recognition of tangientially connected polygons using openCV

Tags: python, numerics, image-processing

Lately, I have encountered the following problem, namely how to recognize the shapes of particular polygons. I have realized that quite straightforward to do so when the polygons are separated by using OpenCV library as shown in the following topics
[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv)
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926449/opencv-shape-detection)

My question, however, is quite more complex and concerns how to detect polygons when they share a side,
like for instance in the picture attached to this question

[image]

Anyone has any suggestions? Maybe some other tool might be able to perform such an analysis?

Comment: The edges form a planar graph, which is substantially easier to analyze than a picture. You need to convert the image into a graph where the vertices of the graph are the joints and the edges of the graph are line segments of the image.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It actually makes it quite easier for me to create a planar graph, since I had to post-process the simulation results (particles forms this kind of ordered network) to represent them as "smooth" polygons as shown in the post. My question is, however, what kind of algorithm would you recommend to work with the approach you suggested?

Comment: Finding triangles corresponds to finding "cliques" in the graph. That's a standard algorithm. You'll find more information about this in computational graph theory books.